# how to save multiple select in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

how to save multiple selcet in laravel when I try the script below, not to save
[image]

this store in controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
  $id = $request->id;
  $post   =   Rek_medik::updateOrCreate(['id' => $id],
              [
                  'kode_rekmed' => $request->kode_rekmed,
                  'kode_register' => $request->kode_register,
                  'kode_pasien' => $request->kode_pasien,
                  'nama_pemeriksa' => $request->nama_pemeriksa,
                  'tgl_rekmed' => Carbon::now(),
                  'anamnesis' => $request->anamnesis,
                  'pemeriksaan' => $request->pemeriksaan,
                  'resep' => $request->resep,
              ]);

  return response()->json($post);
}
```

this is code in view

```
          <div class="form-group">
        <label for="resep">Resep</label>
        <select class="select2bs4"  id="resep" multiple="multiple" name="resep[]" data-placeholder="Select a State"
                style="width: 100%;">
          @foreach($obat as $row)
            <option value="{{$row->kd_obat }}" >{{$row->kd_obat }}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, u can modify your array first before save it to database. I assume your resep column type is varchar. Here's my solution

```
$id = $request->id;
foreach($request->resep[] as $r){
    $resep[] = $r;
}
$post = Rek_medik::updateOrCreate(['id' => $id],
          [
              'kode_rekmed' => $request->kode_rekmed,
              'kode_register' => $request->kode_register,
              'kode_pasien' => $request->kode_pasien,
              'nama_pemeriksa' => $request->nama_pemeriksa,
              'tgl_rekmed' => Carbon::now(),
              'anamnesis' => $request->anamnesis,
              'pemeriksaan' => $request->pemeriksaan,
              'resep' => json_encode($resep),
          ]);

return response()->json($post);
```

json_encode function is to convert $resep array to string. You can change it back to array with json_decode function

```
json_decode($resep);
```

Comment: this works but i doesn't use foreach still work just edit resep 'resep' => $request->resep, to 'resep' => json_encode($resep),

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you try looping through  your multiple select value and save the array's element: Like this : `foreach($request->resep as $item){..then save  your data here..}`.

Comment: it does not work, because it saves into 2 rows of input columns instead of 1 input row, how can I be one row ?

Comment: change your resep column data type to type that accepts an array or an object.I'm sure that will save the `$request->resep` in a single row

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use 'save' function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $id = $request->id;
   $post   =   Rek_medik::updateOrCreate(['id' => $id],
          [
              'kode_rekmed' => $request->kode_rekmed,
              'kode_register' => $request->kode_register,
              'kode_pasien' => $request->kode_pasien,
              'nama_pemeriksa' => $request->nama_pemeriksa,
              'tgl_rekmed' => Carbon::now(),
              'anamnesis' => $request->anamnesis,
              'pemeriksaan' => $request->pemeriksaan,
              'resep' => $request->resep,
          ]);
    $result = $post->save();

   return response()->json($post);
}
```